# Swagger Editor fails to parse definition with enum type parameters

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I use [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) to render API documentation and generate Python client.

I've imported Swagger JSON Definition for [one of public APIs](https://bdl.stat.gov.pl/api/v1/swagger/doc/swagger.json) that get's transformed by the editor into YAML.

However, for parameters of `enum` type I am getting the following error:

```
Structural error at paths./aggregates/metadata.get.parameters.0.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: string, number, boolean, integer, array
Jump to line 23
```

Is it a bug in Swagger Editor, a bug in the definition I picked up or some version incompatibility?

Here's a related Swagger definition in YAML:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: v1
  title: BDL API
  termsOfService: ''
basePath: /api/v1
paths:
  /aggregates/metadata:
    get:
      tags:
        - Aggregates
      summary: Metadane / Metadata
      operationId: AggregatesMetadataGet
      consumes: []
      produces:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      parameters:
        - name: lang
          in: query
          description: ''
          required: false
          type: enum
          enum:
            - pl
            - en
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `type: enum` with `type: string`. This is a syntax error in the API definition and not a Swagger Editor issue.

Another issue in that definition is the redundant `Accept` parameter in operations:

```yaml
  /aggregates/metadata:
    get:
      ...
      produces:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      parameters:
        - ...
        - name: Accept    # <-----
          in: header
          description: ...
          required: false
          type: string
          enum:
            - application/json
            - application/xml
```

The `Accept` header is controlled by the `produces` keyword, there's no need to define it as a parameter. This is technically not an error, but might cause issues with tooling.